# Conda: how should I know from which channel I got a package

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I've installed Anaconda 4.2.9 on my linux machine, and I work with a couple developpers on it, we work on offline mode so we need to download each package from Conda depository and then install it manually.

We face now some compatibility problems between some packages. so I would know from which channel a given package is installed. when I run `conda list` I can see only the local channel I've created:

```
sas7bdat                  2.0.6                    py35_0    file:///opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-4.2.0/channel
scikit-image              0.12.3              np111py35_1
scikit-learn              0.17.1              np111py35_2
scipy                     0.18.1              np111py35_0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to know which channel is used in your case, you have just to take the entire name of your package you have in `conda list --explicit` (as @pilu mentioned in his answer) and google it with `""`.

for example:

```
 file:///opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-4.2.0/channel/linux-64/sas7bdat-2.0.6-py35_0.tar.bz2
```

you have to google: `"sas7bdat-2.0.6-py35_0.tar.bz2"`

you will get the UPLOADER of package (Anaconda for this example).

Answer (score 4):

Try the `explicit` flag:

```
conda list --explicit
```

Comment: `conda list --explicit` gives only the local path of the package: `file:///opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-4.2.0/channel/linux-64/sas7bdat-2.0.6-py35_0.tar.bz2`

Comment: That's a bit weird, for me the output looks like:
`https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64/conda-4.5.1-py36_0.tar.bz2`

Comment: I use the offline mode, this is why

Answer (score 3):

If nothing is listed, then it is part of the default installation.  The default installation packages are associated with the `anaconda` channel.

Comment: what I need is the added packages that they have installed manually like `sas7bdat ` in list below